# Jupyter Notebook bar chart formatting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I've taken a survey where subjects were asked how often they go food shopping and how much they tend to spend. Answers tend to vary, I'm trying to plot all of the frequencies of shopping on the x-axis and the y axis I'm trying to have a number of subjects with the bar split by colour depending on the amount they spend within certain margins. Awful ms paint representation below.

Using pandas and matplotlib

If needed, I can also share the CSV if that would help.

[image: Example of the kind of formatting I'm looking for]

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? And you could add example data to draw it.

Comment: Yes the csv would help. Depending how the data is shaped will greatly affect how this graph get's plotted.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoqDWKNhf46QviAJqz5BdlPJosk3

This is the csv in a onedrive, not sure how to upload the file itself